# Closed-form solution for a probability-related integral?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I'm looking for a closed-form (or any numerically simpler) solution for the following integral:

$$
\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\phi(x,\mu_t,\sigma_t)\Phi(x,\mu_f,\sigma_f)^{(L-1)}dx
$$

where

$\phi(x,\mu_t,\sigma_t)$ is the normal density function evaluated at $x$ with mean $\mu_t$ and standard deviation $\sigma_t$,

$\Phi(x,\mu_f,\sigma_f)$ is the cumulative normal evaluated at $x$ with mean $\mu_f$ and standard deviation $\sigma_f$,

and $L$ is a positive integer.

Note that the means and standard deviations of these two functions are different.

This formula is related to the probability that a sample drawn from the $N(\mu_t,\sigma_t)$ distribution will be higher than $L-1$ samples drawn from the $N(\mu_f,\sigma_f)$ distribution.

I'm also looking for a simplification of the conceptually-related integral:

$$
\int_{c_1}^{c_2}(L-1)\phi(x,\mu_f,\sigma_f)\Phi(x,\mu_f,\sigma_f)^{(L-2)}\Phi(x,\mu_t,\sigma_t)dx
$$

It would also be useful to know if such a thing is not possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_t, \sigma_t^2)$, $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_f, \sigma^2_f)$, and they are independent. Then the integral is equivalent to $\Pr\{c_1 < X < c_2, Y_i < X, i = 1, 2, \ldots, L-1\} = \Pr\{c_1 < X < c_2, Y_i - X < 0, i = 1, 2, \ldots, L-1\}$. So it is in terms of a $L$-dimensional multivariate normal CDF and the components are dependent. I guess this problem numerically is equivalent to evaluating a multivariate normal in general.

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice re-formalization to conceptualize what this expression means. The follow-up question is then, is there a particularly efficient way to compute either the original integral or the reformulated probability in R?